# How do I manually highlight cells by position (not by value) using kableExtra?

Tags: kable, kableextra

Note: I posted a *similar* question about this earlier [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77911674/13942421), but asking for a different solution. I am still interested in that solution, but I am not sure it is possible.

**My question:**
I have a data frame with around 8 columns and 35-40 rows. How can I highlight a specific cell by index/position? I know how to highlight a row or a column or cells that fulfill some logical statement (e.g larger than x).

How can I highlight a cell manually.

In the example below, I would like the **b** in the third row to be highlighted.

Note that I need to do this to about 2*30 different cells (two tables), so it can't be super complicated.

Note also that I do not want to highligh every **b**, just a specific **b**.

```
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(date_one = c("a","b","c"),
                 date_two = c("a","b","b"))


df |> 
  kable(format = "latex")
```

Comment: Can you show your intermediate .tex file? Depending on the code, you might be able to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473887/2777074

Comment: I think you should be able to do it in R though. But thanks!